# calculate CPU Cycle for Java function

Tags: java, python, cpu, cycle

I'd like to know how to calculate the CPU Cycle for a function in Java or Python.

I tried out in Java with:

(OperatingSystemMXBean) ManagementFactory.getOperatingSystemMXBean();
  osbean.getProcessCpuTime();

But no results.

Comment: It's not a trivial subject. The following is a good starting point for Java: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java

Comment: The time it takes to do anything in Java varies based on many factors. The same function might appear to take 50 ms or no time at all depending on what it does and how you run it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**in Python,**

use `timeit.default_timer();` it uses the most accurate option for your platform. in Ubuntu, this will use `time.time()` instead.

`timeit.default_timer()`Define a default timer, in a platform-specific manner. On Windows, `time.clock()` has microsecond granularity, but `time.time()`‘s granularity is `1/60th` of a second. On Unix, `time.clock()` has `1/100th` of a second granularity, and `time.time()` is much more precise. On either platform, `default_timer()` measures wall clock time, not the CPU time. This means that other processes running on the same computer may interfere with the timing.

**in JAVA,**

1. `System.currentTimeMillis()` will only ever measure [wall-clock time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wall_clock_time), never CPU time.
2. If you need wall-clock time, then `System.nanoTime()` is often more precise (and never worse) than `currentTimeMillis()`.
3. `ThreadMXBean.getThreadCPUTime()` can help you find out how much CPU time a given thread has used. Use `ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean()` to get a ThreadMXBean and `Thread.getId()` to find the `id` of the thread you're interested in. Note that this method need not be supported on every JVM!